# How to release memory in ListView on Xamarin UWP?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms UWP application with a ListView in it. The listView contains among other things large images. Soon after loading as I start scrolling the ListView, an OutOfMemory exception occurs. I tried to use paging to make the ListView smaller, but after clicking Next several times, the exception still happens. I wonder how I can release memory e.g. on clicking the Next button.

Here is some code:

```
    <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="ProductView" Margin="20">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                      <Grid>
                          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                          <Image Source="{Binding Front_Image, StringFormat='https://cdn.mysite.com{0}'}" Grid.Column="0" />
                          <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                      </Grid>
                  </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
      <Button x:Name="Prev" Text="Previous" Style="{StaticResource NavButton}" Clicked="OnPrevClicked" IsEnabled="false" />
      <Button x:Name="Next" Text="Next" Style="{StaticResource NavButton}" Clicked="OnNextClicked" />
  </StackLayout>
```

...

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ProductsPage : ContentPage
{
    //public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    private int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;

    public ProductsPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ProductView.ItemsSource = Product.GetProducts(PageNumber);
    }

    private void OnPrevClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ProductView.ItemsSource = Product.GetProducts(--PageNumber);
        Prev.IsEnabled = PageNumber > 1;
    }

    private void OnNextClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ProductView.ItemsSource = Product.GetProducts(++PageNumber);
        Prev.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you can do.

First I would replace the native `Image` and use a package like [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading).

This package provides out of the box solutions for memory management, caching, which is a great help.

You can also check about ListViews Caching Strategies: RecycleElement, which will recycle the views, instead of creating several ViewCells for each element.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and let you know the result.

Comment: Nice, glad  I could help :)

Comment: I would like to share my two cents in addition to @BrunoCaceiro answer:
I,ve had several problems with memory optimization, so I,ve also used an `IDisposable` interface implementation with freeing params memory.